# Datatables not loading data after adding "sDom"

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Im using DataTables (datatables.net) to display my data but when i add the sDom element, no data are loaded to the table.

The below code works

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#table_main').dataTable( {
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url()?>datatable.php"

                });

            });
        </script>
```

although the tags are created that are given in the sDom, none of the data is loaded from he source. and also the button style which are given i fnInitComplete are not being applied

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#table_main').dataTable( {
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url()?>datatable.php",
                    "sDom": "<'dtTop'<'dtShowPer'l><'dtFilter'f>><'dtTables't><'dtBottom'<'dtInfo'i><'dtPagination'p>>",
                         "fnInitComplete": function(){
                                $(".dtShowPer select").uniform();
                                $(".dtFilter input").addClass("simple_field").css({
                                    "width": "auto",
                                    "margin-left": "15px"
                            });
                         }

                });

            });
    </script>
```

any help on how to fix this error will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, documentation says nothing about subclass insertion, so try from working start point with such code (replace same line):

```
"sDom": '<"dtShowPer"l><"dtFilter"f><"dtTables">rt<"dtBottom"><"dtInfo"i><"dtPagination"p>',
```

I dont have any code example with data (but u can provide some on pastebin.com or else), and code seems correct. So just add one rule in sDom and add one-by-one after checking if it works fine.

Comment: i used the code you gave but still doesn't load the data. Even if i add one rule no data are being displayed.. i have added some details at http://pastebin.com/sviHGvKf

Comment: edited. this code work without error for me. i still havent page source.. so make it myself wasting tones of time...(thx for it btw) but now i am sure it's working on 100%.

Comment: cool... it works now (had to make a small change for dtTop) .. thanks a lot mate..